# Matrix manipulation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I wrote the code below:

```
import os
import csv
import numpy as np

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # These two lines give the 
path = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "0.dat")  # path to a file on my disk

with open(path, 'r') as f1:
    listme = csv.reader(f1, delimiter="\t") # I imported the file
    listme2 = list(listme) # I used this command to make a matrix in the next line
    m = np.matrix(listme2)
    m2 = np.delete(m,[1,2],1) # I deleted two columns to get a 2 by 2 matrix

print m + m # It cannot add these two matrix. It also cannot multiply them by np.dot(m,m)
```

I cannot add the matrix I defined to itself. Please read the comment in the code.

The error returned is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'matrix' and 'matrix'
```

Comment: NumPy gives such unhelpful errors when an operation doesn't work due to non-numeric dtype.

Comment: If you're using numpy, you might as well use `np.loadtxt` or one of the other numpy IO routines rather than using `csv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the matter with `+` operator, it's because `m` is a matrix of strings but not numbers. convert `listme2` to a list of numbers before you use it to get `m` if you are ordered to do it manually with [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
listme2=[map(float, line) for line in listme]
```

Or, when creating the matrix, specify the `dtype`:

```
m = np.matrix(listme2, dtype=float)
```

You can also use `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt` to get the 2D array directly without `open` and `csv.reader`. Read the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) yourself ;)

Comment: you can also set the dtype on creation. If they're strings, numpy will do the conversion to numbers.

Comment: @zhangxaochen How can I convert "listme2" to a list of numbers?
Is it possible to import the data directly as a matrix of numbers?

Comment: @zhangxaochen Thank you. The second suggestion works. I also want to know how to convert "listme2" to a list of numbers.